# How to resolve dependency tree with different version ranges of same packages?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, happstack

I'm trying to set up a *happstack-lite* application using *stack*.

I initialized project with these commands:

```
stack new my-happstack
cd my-happstack
stack setup
```

I changed **package.yaml** so it contains:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- happstack-lite >= 7.3
```

Then I ran **stack build** several times and changed **extra-deps** in **stack.yaml** in project directory according to recommendations (added dependencies, such as *happstack-server*).

Apparently, I was asked to add to **extra-deps** the packages already listed there, with different version bounds and one with the same (*template-haskell-2.11.1.0*):

**stack.yaml** content:

```
extra-deps:
- happstack-lite-7.3.6
- happstack-server-7.4.6.4
- Win32-2.2.2.0@sha256:10ed55dd31315f386910c121c1d1d442df83bd2ee92090a753cd65300735a8ca
- network-2.6.3.6@sha256:1ca79d81af02d7acd6032d5e6c9bde4618a8fdcfbe19bd42b49d420183975df0
- template-haskell-2.11.1.0@sha256:f90d6ab73ad35c749e8547ca132e7ab5d32d2f8e7bb2e2ff6d597be26b58e061
- transformers-compat-0.5.1.4@sha256:1b4bfa8589afb1ca0e719129ab261bd90ef0cc3e6c0b9963f94970c082b61250
```

output from **stack build**:

```
F:\Projects\Haskell\my-happstack>stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for Cabal-2.4.1.0:
    Win32-2.2.2.0 from stack configuration does not match >=2.3.0.0 && <2.9  (latest matching
                  version is 2.8.3.0)
needed due to my-happstack-0.1.0.0 -> Cabal-2.4.1.0

In the dependencies for happstack-server-7.4.6.4:
    template-haskell-2.14.0.0 from stack configuration does not match <2.12  (latest matching
                              version is 2.11.1.0)
needed due to my-happstack-0.1.0.0 -> happstack-server-7.4.6.4

In the dependencies for transformers-base-0.4.5.2:
    transformers-compat-0.5.1.4 from stack configuration does not match >=0.6.1  (latest matching
                                version is 0.6.4)
needed due to my-happstack-0.1.0.0 -> transformers-base-0.4.5.2

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in C:\sr\config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some
    working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated
    constraint errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
    in F:\Projects\Haskell\my-happstack\stack.yaml:

Win32-2.8.3.0@sha256:58fa6f52e8a0d455a74bb19445c177f2cc79a0975cae5fd96e2334bd38a516d4
template-haskell-2.11.1.0@sha256:f90d6ab73ad35c749e8547ca132e7ab5d32d2f8e7bb2e2ff6d597be26b58e061
transformers-compat-0.6.4@sha256:d298cd9d1bb7b05160229e244436bae825b53660865e3d5fd695ea0fafec1e6f

Plan construction failed.
```

I've tried these steps:

1) Set **'allow-newer: true'** in **C:\sr\config.yaml**. In this case, I'm getting error about wrong types usage from inside one of the dependent packages (can paste error output upon request, if needed).

2) Run **stack solver**. I've got the error from cabal planner (error output upon request).

So, I expect *stack* to resolve dependencies the way *npm* does - each package dependencies are resolved independently from other's packages needs. Any advice of how I can solve this particular problem will be helpful, though (including manual dependencies resolving).